# mySql subtract row of different table

Tags: mysql, subtraction

I want to subtract between two rows of different table:

I have created a `view` called `leave_taken` and `table` called `leave_balance`.

I want this result from both table:

```
leave_taken.COUNT(*) - leave_balance.balance
```

and group by `leave_type_id_leave_type`

**Code of both table**

-----------------View Leave_Taken-----------

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER=`1`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `leave_taken` 
AS 
   select 
     `leave`.`staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff` AS `staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff`,
     `leave`.`leave_type_id_leave_type` AS `leave_type_id_leave_type`,
     count(0) AS `COUNT(*)` 
   from 
   (
      `leave` 
      join `staff` on((`staff`.`id_staff` = `leave`.`staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff`))
   ) 
   where (`leave`.`active` = 1) 
   group by `leave`.`leave_type_id_leave_type`;
```

----------------Table leave_balance----------

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leave_balance` (
  `id_leave_balance` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `staff_id_staff` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `leave_type_id_leave_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `balance` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_leave_balance`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_leave_balance_UNIQUE` (`id_leave_balance`),
  KEY `fk_leave_balance_staff1` (`staff_id_staff`),
  KEY `fk_leave_balance_leave_type1` (`leave_type_id_leave_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

------- Table leave ----------

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leave` (
  `id_leave` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `staff_leave_application_id_staff_leave_application` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `leave_type_id_leave_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date_updated` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_leave`,`staff_leave_application_id_staff_leave_application`,`staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff`),
  KEY `fk_table1_leave_type1` (`leave_type_id_leave_type`),
  KEY `fk_table1_staff_leave_application1` (`staff_leave_application_id_staff_leave_application`,`staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;
```

Comment: So the result that you are  looking for `leave_taken.COUNT(*) - leave_balance.balance` is only one value? i.e `leave_taken.COUNT(*) - SUM(leave_balance.balance)` or for each row in the `leave_balance`?

Comment: My intuition tells me to **never** name a field `COUNT(*)` (I wouldn't even have thought that that's possible), to avoid unnecessary confusion, reduced readability and unexpected results from syntactic near-ambiguity.

Comment: Can you give us the table structure for the `leave` table? And maybe some sample data for each? I'm wondering if you need to create a view at all for this...

Comment: @jakerella updated question, added leave table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I still don't think you've provided enough information. It would be **very** helpful to have some sample data and your expected output (in tabular format). That said, I may have something you can start working with. This query finds all staff members, calculates their current leave (grouped by type), and determines the difference between that and their balance by leave type. Take a look at it, and more importantly (perhaps) the [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc8fb/24) that I used which has the sample data in it (very important to determining if this is the correct path for your data).

```
SELECT
    staff.id_staff,
    staff.name,
    COUNT(`leave`.id_leave) AS leave_count,
    leave_balance.balance,
    (COUNT(`leave`.id_leave) - leave_balance.balance) AS leave_difference,
    `leave`.leave_type_id_leave_type AS leave_type
  FROM
    staff
    JOIN `leave` ON staff.id_staff = `leave`.staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff
    JOIN leave_balance ON
      (
        staff.id_staff = leave_balance.staff_id_staff
        AND `leave`.leave_type_id_leave_type = leave_balance.leave_type_id_leave_type
      )
  WHERE 
    `leave`.active = 1
  GROUP BY
    staff.id_staff, leave_type;
```

Good luck!